# PHP Inheritance between class methods without overloading it, just merge it

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

ok i have 2 classes

```
class A{  
     public function say(){
        echo "hello<br>";
     }  
  }

 class B extends A{
    public function say(){
        echo "hi<br>";
    }
 }

 $haha = new B();
 $haha->say();
```

well as you see i overloaded the method say() in class b... but what i want here is to merge the two methods and not overwrite each other. my desired output I want is this

```
hello<br>
hi<br>
```

is this possible?

NOTE: if my terms are wrong, please teach me the right terms. I am really new to PHP OOP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**
Based on your comments, you want something like this:

```
class A{
    final public function say(){
        echo "hello<br>";
        $this->_say();
    }
    
    public function _say(){
        //By default, do nothing
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function _say(){
        echo "Hi<br>";
    }
}
```

I have called the new function `_say`, but you can give it any name you want. This way, your teammates just define a method called _say(), and it will automatically be called by class `A`'s say method.

This is called the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

**Old answer**

Just add `parent::say();` to the overloading method:

```
class B extends A{
    public function say(){
        parent::say();
        echo "hi<br>";
    }
 }
```

This tells php to execute the overloaded method. If you don't want extending classes to overload it's methods, you can declare them [final](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php).

See also the php manual about [extending](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends) classes.

Comment: is there any other way that I will not need to use `parent`?

Comment: ok thank you.. hmm...but can you give me some advice? because I want to create a class that its methods will not be overloaded.. or if its not really possible ok i understand ^^

Comment: @Mahan Why would you not want to use `parent`?

Comment: because my teammates would have tendencies not to write it, what i really want here is to create a method that will run along the `say()` method if its invoked