# php check if method overridden in child class

Tags: php, oop, overloading

Is it possible to check whether or not a method has been overridden by a child class in PHP?

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

class foo {
    protected $url;
    protected $name;
    protected $id;

    var $baz;

    function __construct($name, $id, $url) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    function createTable($data) {
        // do default actions
    }
}
```

Child class:

```php
class bar extends foo {
    public $goo;

    public function createTable($data) {
        // different code here
    }
}
```

When iterating through an array of objects defined as members of this class, how can I check which of the objects has the new method as opposed to the old one? Does a function such as `method_overridden(mixed $object, string $method name)` exist?

```php
foreach ($objects as $ob) {
    if (method_overridden($ob, "createTable")) {
        // stuff that should only happen if this method is overridden
    }
    $ob->createTable($dataset);
}
```

I am aware of the [template method pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389578/php-inheritance-between-class-methods-without-overloading-it-just-merge-it), but let's say I want the control of the program to be separate from the class and the methods themselves. I would need a function such as `method_overridden` to accomplish this.

Comment: Overloaded, or overridden? I thought PHP didn't have method overloading

Comment: I did mean over-ridden, yes

Comment: You could try this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php

Comment: If your design is dependant on knowing how classes have overridden particular methods, then there's something seriously wrong with your design.  The whole idea behind OO is that you can send a message to an object and it's up to the object to handle it in an appropriate way.  The calling code shouldn't care what implementation is being called or how its message is being dealt with.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check if the declaring class matches the class of the object:

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionMethod($ob, 'createTable');
$isProto = ($reflector->getDeclaringClass()->getName() !== get_class($ob));
```

PHP Manual links:

- [ReflectionMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)
- [ReflectionProperty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php)

Comment: This is certainly the way I want to go about it, but I have a question: for what reason are you using the namespace operator before ReflectionMethod? Is it to ensure that method is being called from the global namespace instead of accidentally calling a method of the same name defined in a more local scope?

Comment: It's probably not needed in your case. If the code above is under a namespace, you would need to either import the ReflectionMethod class, or access it with global namespace prefix (`\\`). I'm just making sure this situation is handled :)

Comment: This can be done with class properties as well. Just use `\ReflectionProperty()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To get this information, you have to use ReflectionClass. You could try getMethod and check the class name of the method.

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($this);
$method = $class->getMethod("yourMethod");
if ($method->class == 'classname') {
    //.. do something
}
```

But keep in mind, that reflection isn't very fast, so be careful with usage.

Comment: In PHP 5.5.20 the `$method['class']` gave me: _Cannot use object of type ReflectionMethod as array_. The `$method->class` worked just fine.