# In PHP is it possible to tell if a method is called explicitly by parent::

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to tell if a method in the parent class is called explicitly by parent:: as opposed to being called automatically because the sub class doesn't contain the method being called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php check if method overridden in child class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663178/php-check-if-method-overridden-in-child-class)

Comment: Not without tracing via debug_backtrace.... but it should never be necessary for your method to know how or from where it has been called

Comment: yeah i think that other post does answer this question - what's the etiquette? should i delete the question?

Comment: Imo your classes shouldn't change their behaviour based on who calls the method or any other logic of this kind. I believe that the point of classes/objects is to group/separate independent functionality if what you need doesn't fit in to that and MUST change depending on who calls a method or instantiates it, well you either have to change your are doing it wrong.

Comment: The reason for why: it's a controller in an mvc web app. The parent controller provides basic CRUD functionality. The simpler resources work fine using the methods in the parent class but more complex resources need some extra functionality. The methods in the parent still provide useful initialisation stuff for the more complex overriding methods but the final thing they do is render the template so I was thinking I could check if the parent methods was being called from a child class methods and if not then not render the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I'm not sure you can get it easily.
anyway, I think you could follow one of this way, if you need a work-around:

example 1:

```
class Par

{
    function printit($which = false)
    {
        // when you call this method, based on variable it tells how it was called
        if ($which) {
            echo "called with parent \n";
        } else {
            echo "called with this \n";
        }
    }
}

class Chi extends Par

{
    function callParent()
    {
        parent::printit(TRUE);
    }

    function callFunction()
    {
        $this->printit(FALSE);
    }
}

$chi = new Chi();
$chi->callParent();
$chi->callFunction();
```

example 2:

```
class Par

{
    function printit()
    {
        // get all functions in child class
        $child_methods = array_diff(get_class_methods("Chi") , get_class_methods("Par"));
        // if the function there is in child class, probably it was called from there
        if (in_array(__FUNCTION__, $child_methods)) {
            echo "called with child \n";
        } else {
            echo "called with parent \n";
        }
    }
}

class Chi extends Par

{
    function callParent()
    {
        parent::printit();
    }

    function callFunction()
    {
        $this->printit();
    }
}

$chi = new Chi();
$chi->callParent();
$chi->callFunction();
```

Comment: i would give the $which parameter a default value of false